# Filling NaN with object values throws an error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas

I need to fill missing values with nemurical or categorical values (depending on column type). I wrote a function which calculates median for each year and fills missings with this value (numerical column) and for categorical columns - fills missings with most frequent value in each year. I prepared a test dataframe to test the function. My function works fine for this dataframe - fills missing values for categorical and numerical columns.

The issue is that when I use this function on my real dataset it doesn't work on categorical column (of type `object`) but it works fine on numerical column. The following error shows up:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

I can't throw the whole dataset here an reproducible example doesn't throw any error but maybe you know where the problem might lie?

```
dataset = {'song_year': ['1999', '2000', '2000', '2000','2000'],
        'song_popularity': [20.0, 33.8, 19.1, np.nan, 55.9],
        'country': ['USA', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'Italy', np.nan]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)


def mapNullsWithValues(data, col_key, col_vals):
    
    to_df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    if (data[col_vals].dtype == object) | (data[col_vals].dtype == 'category'):
        to_df = data.groupby(col_key)[col_vals].agg(pd.Series.mode).to_frame().reset_index()
    elif (data[col_vals].dtype == 'float64') | (data[col_vals].dtype == 'int64'):
        to_df = data.groupby(col_key)[col_vals].median().to_frame().reset_index()
    
    col_keys = to_df.iloc[:,0].values
    col_values = to_df.iloc[:,1].values

    dictionary = dict(zip(col_keys, col_values))
    
    data[col_vals].fillna(data[col_key].map(dictionary), inplace=True)
 
   
mapNullsWithValues(df, 'song_year', 'country')    
mapNullsWithValues(df, 'song_year', 'song_popularity')
```

Comment: Maybe you try to use an `ndarray` as dict key.

Comment: I changed method to `to_numpy()` but it doesn't help: `col_keys = to_df.iloc[:,0].to_numpy()`

Comment: Ok, I found an error. One of my entries was an array (`col_vals`), that's why I got an error.

Comment: you can close the question, if you solved it.